# How to replace entire CSS of a page after an ajax request with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, head

I have a document with one CSS linked in. How can I replace the current CSS with one coming from a document that I just fetched with AJAX request using jQuery?

Here's the code I am trying right now, but with no success so far:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('next_page.html', function(data, textStatus) {
        $('link[rel=stylesheet]:first')
            .attr('href', $(data).find('link[rel=stylesheet]:first').attr('href'));
    });
});
```

> **Update:** $.find() does not work in any browser (tested Firefox 3.5,
>   Chrome and Safari 3 on Mac), but
>   $.filter() found the stylesheet only
>   in Firefox 3.5 - still nothing in
>   Chrome and Safari 3.

It should be plain simple, right - replace the current CSS href with the new one, and voilá?

For some reason, jQuery fails to find anything inside the `<head>` tag that is coming from AJAX request. Furthermore, jQuery even fails to find the whole `<head>` itself from the AJAX data. In other words, `$(data).find('head').size()` inside the callback function returns 0.

I am using jQuery 1.4.

---

**UPDATE Feb 10, 2010: I filed a bug about this to jQuery and they agreed it is not possible to find anything from the `<head>` tag from an ajax data.**
Here's the response I got:

> http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6061#comment:1 — "Yep, that's correct - parsing
>   straight HTML we only guarantee the
>   contents of the body element. If you
>   wish to access the XML of the page
>   directly then I recommend that you
>   explicitly make the file .xhtml or
>   request it as XML, for example:"

Comment: Could the problem be that the ajax results is not loaded into the DOM, so jQuery searching for it within the DOM will not work?

Try appending it as a child to an invisible div on current_page, then see if you can grab the link tag (then delete the div afterwards for tidyness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid as per jQuery dev team — "parsing straight HTML we only guarantee the contents of the body element. If you wish to access the XML of the page directly then I recommend that you explicitly make the file .xhtml or request it as XML, for example:"

```
$.ajax({ dataType: "xml", file: "some.html", success: function(data){ ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

This jquery should do it:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("next_page.html", function(data) {
            $("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href", $(data).filter("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href"));
        });
    });
```

Comment: This does not work either! :( Seems jQuery is failing to find the whole <head> tag from ajax data.

Comment: Update: $.filter() finds the stylesheet in Firefox (ver 3.5 on Mac), but does not work neither in Google Chrome nor Safari (on Mac). So it's unfortunately still not solved.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the response type.  I tested that and it is text/html in IE, FF, and Chrome (don't have Safari to test).  For some reason, the attr("href") after filter won't find the href attribute value.  Is there a reason you use a different page to get the url for the new stylesheet?  Why don't you just use a link on the page and take the url from there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.load('next_page.html', function(data) {
    $('link[rel=stylesheet]:first').replaceWith($(data).find('link[rel=stylesheet]:first'));
});
```

You were not actually making an AJAX call in your own example, perhaps that was the problem or you just forgot to add the `.load` part? This should work just fine, given that it is inside the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block.

Comment: sorry, I did forgot the .get part.. I edited my question so it's correct now.

Comment: still, this does not solve the problem because $(data).find('link[rel=stylesheet]') is not found

Comment: @Martin, what does your `data` look like?

Comment: data is a full xhtml 1.0 transitional page

Comment: have you validated it? perhaps it's more transitional than you think

Answer (score 0):

i have it working on my site. I simply added an id to my link tag where my css is loaded. and then you change the attri href (you got that part right).

HTML:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/llt_style/skin/nuit.css" rel="stylesheet" id="llt_skin_href"/>
```

And the i use a select to let the user choose his skin.

```
<select onchange="$('#llt_skin_href').attr('href', $(this).val());">
    <option value="/llt_style/skin/jour.css">Jour</option>
    <option value="/llt_style/skin/nuit.css">Nuit</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can sse the PLAIN JS working here:
http://louisloudogtrottier.net/configuration+Utilisateur/Couleur+du+site (soory, site is in french cause of the law where i live. Nuit is the dark theme, and jour is the light theme.